# Symbol at top of the web page

Tags: html

I was making a website using bootstrap, ">" i got this at the top website. I went through the html code , there was no such writing done by me.. but this symbol is being shown in the chrome inspect section.. its not going . what do i do?? you can see at the top left corner.[my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGcnd.png)
i have googled it found nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">">
</head>
<body>
  <section id="title">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      </div
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line you seem to have accidentally left `">` at the end:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">">
```

Just remove that and it should work.